# How to disable the built-in advertising on LibreOffice 6.1+?

Tags: libreoffice

With version 6.1, LibreOffice now incorporates a distracting nag bar/infobar to interfere with the user interface while requesting that users "Get Involved" and "Donate" (presumably on the theory that people will donate, then keep donating each time the reminder pops up?).

How can I eliminate this behavior permanently?

Answers arguing that the ad-ware belongs in LibreOffice are unwelcome. Please take that to some other forum.

Comment: On "Answers arguing that the ad-ware belongs in LibreOffice are unwelcome. Please take that to some other forum.": I don't know why those banners (occurring once after upgrading the version, right?) are disturbing you, but I think it's fair to remind people that free software cannot be made without expenses. I myself contributed yearly even before those banners...

Comment: @U.Windl "occurring once after upgrading the version, right?" False. They recur.

Comment: It seems the got more annoying recently; in the past I only saw them once after updating the software.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How to eliminate this behavior permanently?

Within LibreOffice, view the Open Expert Configuration¹ and search for `LastTime`.   Change the values of `LastTimeGetInvolvedShown` and `LastTimeDonateShown` to the maximum allowed value of `2147483646`.

The value is a UNIX timestamp of when the infobar was last shown.

Source: [Get Involved - Infobar](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/get-involved-nag-line/37801)

---

¹ To find this, select menu - **Tools**/**Options**, and in the Options dialog, navigate to **LibreOffice/Advanced** - the "Open Expert Configuration" button should be on that page.

Answer (score 12):

#### How can I eliminate this behavior permanently?

There is a [Stop Begging](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/867) extension in the LibreOffice Extension and Templates Repository:

> Prevent the infobar from asking for more money or involvement at startup.
>
> Starting in LibreOffice 6.2, every 90 days you will be asked either for more money or to increase your involvement. This configuration/settings extension disables that timer, so that you never see these infobar notices.

Source: [Stop Begging » Extensions](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/867)

There is also a bug report regarding this issue [120271 – Disabling "Get involved" and "Donate" infobar in enterprise installs](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=120271)