# How to disable the built-in update nag on LibreOffice 7.3?

Tags: libreoffice

The good people making LibreOffice have built in a "Hey there's a new version" pop-up nag and toolbar indicator. It does this several times a day, even though I click to dismiss it every time.

However, I am already using the newest **stable release** version (7.3.7.2 as of this writing), and am not interested in the development (aka "power user") version.

How can I permanently disable this distracting, obnoxious and poorly designed update reminder without upgrading to the unstable development release?

Note: Frame challenges about the desirability of this update notification feature are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever gone into Options? Seems like it's time to do it - [**Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Online Update**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/optionen/online_update.html)

[image: Check for updates automatically]

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much.  Thankfully, that is simpler than [disabling the nag bars for LO's advertising](https://superuser.com/q/1708502/866124).